# Не работает элемент Chart WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

Проект работает корректно на винде, но на маке выбивает ошибку System.NotImplementedException. The method or operation is not implemented. В каждой строчке где идет взаимодействие с элементом chart. Код для chart:

```
chartArea2.Name = "ChartArea1";
this.chart1.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea2);
legend2.Enabled = false;
legend2.Name = "Legend1";
this.chart1.Legends.Add(legend2);
this.chart1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(282, 195);
this.chart1.Name = "chart1";
series2.ChartArea = "ChartArea1";
series2.ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Spline;
series2.Legend = "Legend1";
series2.Name = "Series1";
this.chart1.Series.Add(series2);
this.chart1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(517, 253);
this.chart1.TabIndex = 4;
this.chart1.Text = "chart1";
```

Почему эта ошибка если на винде все работает. Версия фреймворка 4.7.2

Comment: Windows Forms могут работать только в Windows. Та и .NET Framework тоже, в отличии от .NET

Comment: **Windows** Forms